# How to add a C wire to a lennox G8-137 wd-64280-L5

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I have a Lennox G8-137 WD-64280-L5 furnace. I am trying to update the wiring going to the thermostat due to it being cloth covered, and I also plan to put in a google nest thermostat.  Where is my C wire?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The nut with the blue wires in it is your C wire

According to your unit's wiring diagram, the yellow wire from the transformer goes off to the thermostat, which'd make it R.  So, the other secondary wire, aka the blue wire from the transformer, must be C, and they even have provided a convenient wirenut junction in that box for you to tap into it at.